# The error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' sometimes causes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning web-scraping with Python(3.7) and BS4 by extracting data from a horse race result website. The website is http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/Meeting/Results/English/Local/20080412/ST/5

Here is a part of my code. The main purpose is tried to get the data from the table > tbody > tr > td. The class of the table is `{'class': 'tableBorder trBgBlue tdAlignC number12 draggable'}`

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theURL = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/Meeting/Results/English/Local/20080412/ST/5"
thePage = urllib.request.urlopen(theURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thePage, "html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tableBorder trBgBlue tdAlignC number12 draggable'})
tBody = table.find('tbody')
for tRows in tBody.find_all('tr'):
   # Get the td.text
```

Sometimes I can get all the data inside the table and write to a csv file. But sometimes the following error will be caused.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/fyp/raceRecord.py", line 32, in <module>
    tBody = table.find('tbody')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I understand that this error will be caused because `table.find('tbody')` is returning `None`. However, I don't know why sometimes the code works but sometimes doesn't. Is it because the page still loading so `table.find('tbody') = None`? Thanks.

Comment: That's not what's happening. `table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tableBorder trBgBlue tdAlignC number12 draggable'})` is returning `None`, presumably through there being no matches. This then leads `table.find('tbody')` to become `None.find('tbody')`, which throws your error.

Comment: You could check easily if your theory is right by keeping the html that causes the error and take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve the issue. The page is not loading properly when the **"urllib.request.urlopen"** is being performed. The code is checking whether the table is there.
Please check and let me know. Thank you.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theURL = "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/Info/Meeting/Results/English/Local/20080412/ST/5"
while (True):
    thePage = urllib.request.urlopen(theURL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thePage, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tableBorder trBgBlue tdAlignC number12 draggable'})
    if (table != None):
        tBody = table.find('tbody')
        break
```

Answer (score -3):

i was also having the same problem, then i included sleep for 3 seconds above the line of code where it was returning a NoneType object
after that, it is working gracefully

from time import sleep

sleep(3) #wherever necessary